# Group by month-year python pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a set of dates in the following format:

```
01/02/2022
01/02/2022
02/02/2022
01/03/2022
```

How would I group by month and year?

Ideal desired output would be:

```
Feb-2022
Mar-2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["column1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["column1"], dayfirst=True)

out = df["column1"].dt.strftime("%b-%Y").drop_duplicates()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
0    Feb-2022
3    Mar-2022
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

---

Input dataframe:

```
      column1
0  01/02/2022
1  01/02/2022
2  02/02/2022
3  01/03/2022
```